# Notepad++ Replace same word in different lines with words from a list

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with random lines, but each of them contains the same word. Example:

- Mark goes to school YYY
- Anna is looking at university YYY
- John doesn't like YYY
- ...

How can I change YYY with words from a predefined list like:

- Dublin High School
- UCLA
- Stanford University

Output would be:

- Mark goes to school Dublin High School
- Anna is looking at university UCLA
- John doesn't like Stanford University

Comment: Npp can't do that, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Macro feature** of Notepad++:

**Precondition:** the number of lines in file two matches **exactly** the number of times string YYY occurs.

1. copy the second files content to the top of the first file.
2. Use Macro -> Start Recording
3. Press Ctrl + Pos1 to move the cursor to the start of the first line
4. Press Shift + End to mark the first line
5. Press Ctrl + X to cut the first line into the clipboard
6. Press Del to remove the now empty first line
7. Use Search -> Find to open the find dialog, enter YYY, press Enter, press Escape
8. Now the first occurence of YYY is marked, press Ctl + V to replace it with Clipboard content (the former first line)
9. Use Macro -> Stop Recording
10. Now Use Macro -> Run a Macro Multiple Times, Chose Run x times, enter **"the number of lines in the second file" minus one**, as we have used the first line during the macro recording.